# Represent n as an expression containing all the digits

Tags: code-golf, expression-building

Related Challenge: [Single Digit Representations of Natural Numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200185/single-digit-representations-of-natural-numbers)

## Task

Write a program/function that when given a non-negative integer \$n \le 100000\$ outputs an expression which uses all the digits from \$0\$ to \$9\$ exactly once and evaluates to \$n\$

The expression outputted by your program may only use the operations listed below:

- addition
- subtraction and unary minus (both must have the same symbol)
- multiplication
- division (fractional, i.e. 1/2 = 0.5)
- exponentiation
- parentheses

**Note:** Concatenation is **not** allowed

## Output Format

- Output can be a string, list of operations and numbers or a list of lists in place of brackets.
- You may choose the precedence of the operators but it must be consistent for all outputs produced by your program/function
- Output may be in [polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), [reverse polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) or [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) notation but it must be consistent for all outputs produced by your program/function.
- You can use custom symbols for representing the digits and operations but the symbols used for representing the digits and operations should be distinct.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins

## Sample Testcases

```
0 -> 0 ^ (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9)
4 -> (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8) / 9
7 -> 0 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 9) + 7
45 -> 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
29 -> 1 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 0 + (9 - 8)
29 -> (((9 + 8 + 7 + 6) * 0) + 5 + 4) * 3 + 2 * 1
100 -> (9 * 8) + 7 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
```

---

A [proof by exhaustion](https://gist.github.com/Mukundan314/ee97fb46122a514fee5961e3bb3e949e) (also contains program used to generate the proof) that shows that all number less than or equal to \$100000\$ have an expression that uses all the digits.

Comment: Seeing as the very first thing you do is link to a challenge that allows it, I think you should explicitly state that concatenation isn't permitted here.

Comment: A test case or 2 with input `<10` would be handy, too.

Comment: Is not including concatenation really different enough to make this not a duplicate?

Comment: This challenge is literally just asking people to brute force putting digits and symbols together until the output matches. It is pointless because you made the rules so loose.  Either add a time limit per execution or simply state that brute force is not an option because these programs will never fully execute in reasonable time

Comment: @pppery, please read the other question it is pretty different.

Comment: @JBernardo, yes the challenge is just asking for a brute force, that is how i ment this challenge to be.

Comment: So I guess you will run these programs til the end of times to see if they produce right results?

Comment: @JBernardo Code golf are usually like that. It's *possible* to set a time limit condition (either "the program must run in 10 seconds on my machine" or "you must be able to run the program to completion"), but people don't usually do that here.

Comment: @Mukundan314 - Thanks for the info that division isn't required up to 100k, and the updated proof-by-exhaustion.  I notice that your proof, as well as my own R answer, both use fully-nested parentheses in infix (equivalent to alternating digits & operators in RPN).  This isn't required by the challenge, so it seems still possible that other operators might become superfluous by re-arranging the parehtneses...  unless you know something that I don't...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen yes that is correct other operators might not be necessary when having more complicated parentheses but if you do submit an answer which uses more complicated parentheses and fewer operators then please also include a proof of why your answer can generate expressions for all numbers from 0 to 100k

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid that it would probably make my code (even) longer and (even) slower...

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
9Ýœ"+-*m"9ãðδšδ.ιJ˜.Δ.VQ
```

Brute-force approach, so obviously extremely slow.
Outputs in reverse Polish notation, with the characters `+-*m` for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and exponentiation respectively. Division isn't necessary for the \$[0,100000]\$ range we have to support.

[Try it online with additional (first) input to specify the digit-range \$[0,n]\$ instead of \$[0,9]\$](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9vc2FiaWX//8K5w53FkyIrLSptIsK5w6PDsM60xaHOtC7OuUrLnC7OlC5WUf//NAoyNQ), for which I've used `4` right now as example.

**Explanation:**

```python
9Ý           # Push a list in the range [0,9]
  œ          # Get all possible permutations of this list
"+-*m"       # Push string "+-*m"
      9ã     # Get all possible combinations of size 9 with the cartesian product
         δ   # Map over each string of operations:
        ð š  #  Convert it to a list of characters, and prepend a space
δ            # Apply double-vectorized with both lists of lists:
 .ι          #  Interleave the lists
J            # Then join each inner list together to a string
.Δ           # Find the first string which is truthy for:
  .V         #  Evaluate/execute the string as 05AB1E code
    Q        #  And check if the result is equal to the (implicit) input-integer
             # (after which the found result is output implicitly)
```

If we are allowed to output all possible results instead of just one, the `.Δ` (find first) could be `ʒ` (filter) for -1 byte. Although in that case it would become even slower than it already is..

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain why? I don't mind being downvoted, but I'd like to know why so I can improve and keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: there's been a spate of downvotes on solutions in golfing languages this week.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, it's that time of year again.

Comment: division isn't actually required. plus, minus, multiply and exponentiation are enough to get all number from 0 to 100000

Comment: @Mukundan314 Is it also true that all numbers can be achieved by executing each operation in turn i.e. you never have to do e.g. `(a+b)*(c+d)`?

Comment: @Neil yes that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>249</s> <s>244</s> <s>234</s> <s>224</s> <s>220</s> 200 bytes

Or [R](https://www.r-project.org/)+arrangements library, <s>237</s> <s>232</s> <s>222</s> <s>212</s> <s>208</s> 188 bytes (and somewhat faster)

*Multiple edits: -15 bytes thanks to Mukundan314 (no division needed), -4 bytes thanks to 'my pronoun is monicareinstate', -10 bytes by outputting in Polish (prefix) notation, and (latest) -20 bytes by outputting as error message*

```r
function(n){apply(gtools::permutations(10,10)-1,1,function(k)apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:4),9)),1,function(l){for(m in 10:1)F=c(`+`,`-`,`*`,`^`)[[c(l,1)[m]]](F,k[11-m])
if(F==n)stop(letters[l],k)}))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LCsIwEEX3foXLGU2lA25a6LY/EaKNbVpC8yJJQRG/vVYEcXFWl8PhxtXKWV3dYm8qNuu4uD5r78DhU4ZgHjBl702q66CiXbL8jAmoZFRiQYzYz5jxK6h7kG44TVEPEFUAo1MGqs/IKsR/weBz9BHsXrs9lTVh2/TQHTvWFRuHjUuHnPdgGCG3Qgho2cyJCitwp0dom8Zhyn5rqJxVTNwINuML8fX/CqoK1zc)

Outputs **as error message**, in Polish notation using 'a' to denote plus, 'b' to denote minus, 'c' to denote multiply, and 'd' to denote exponentiation.

Commented version before golfing (with more-readable output that can be copy-pasted to directly check):

```r
make_number=function(n,with=0:9) {
    i=arrangements::permutations(with)          # all the permutations of the digits 0..9
    j=as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(1:5),length(with)-1))) 
                                                # all the combinations of 1..5 (for the 5 operators)
    o=c("+"=`+`,"-"=`-`,"*"=`*`,"/"=`/`,"^"=`^`)
                                                # the 5 operators that we can use
    for(k in 1:nrow(i)){for(l in 1:nrow(j)){    # cycle through the permutations of digits & operators
        t=i[k,1]                                # total starts as first digit
        for(m in 2:length(with)-1){t=o[[j[l,m]]](t,i[k,m+1])}
                                                # apply all the operators using each next digit
        if(!is.na(t)&&(t==n)){                  # if we get the answer we're looking for...
                                                # return a string with the calculation
            return( paste0( paste0(rep("(",ncol(j)),collapse=""),paste0(c("",names(o)[j[l,]]),i[k,],collapse=")"))) 
        }
    }}
}

> make_number(1)
[1] "(((((((((0)-1)-2)-3)*4)-5)+6)+7)+8)+9"
> make_number(99)
[1] "(((((((((0)+1)/2)+3)+4)+5)*6)+7)+8)+9"
> make_number(1234)
[1] "(((((((((0)*1)+2)+3)^4)/5)+6)+7)*9)-8"
```

Note that this algorithm will always find first (and stop at) a solution with the smallest rearrangment of the digits from the starting order of 0..9.

Comment: division isn't actually required. plus, minus, multiply and exponentiation are enough to get all number from 0 to 100000

Comment: Is there really any reason to stop at 262144 and not simply iterate until 1e9? (I don't know R)

Comment: That number is the columns in the matrix of permutations of operators. There are 4 operators, assigned to 9 positions, so 4^9=262144. This saves a character compared to writing ```ncol(j)```.  It's an inner loop, so it needs to terminate correctly.

Comment: But it's a good suggestion for the outer loop (currently ```ncol(i)```), which should never go beyond the end because it should have already found a solution. Thanks!

Comment: It works for me (on the only test case) if I replace 262144 with 3e5.

Comment: TLDR - you're probably right, but it's risky without proving it for all 100001 cases.  3e5 will crash for any number (eg 163) that can't be solved with the digits in 0..9 order, since the inner loop will over-run.  2e5 won't crash, but it won't sample all the possible permutations of operators.  Due to the order of the operator list and the fact that 2e5 > 3/4 * 262144, the only permutations that will be missed are those with exponentiation as the first-used operator.  It seems very likely to me that this will still allow all numbers up to 100k to be generated, but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Note that I've now found a way to avoid defining these loop sizes altogether (enabled by outputting in an error message...), which will hopefully avoid the need to generate the 'no-first-exponentiation' proof just to save 3 bytes...

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 84 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔”y⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹”ε≔ＶεηＷ¬ω«≔⭆◧Ｉηχ§εΣκζ≦⊕η¿⬤ε№ζκＦＸ⁴¦⁹«≔⭆⁹§”y⁺×⁻Ｘ”÷κＸ⁴λδ¿⁼Ｖ⁺δ⪫ζ´¦θ≔δω»»ωζ
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNTsMwEIXXzSmsrMZSkEBiU3VVlS6CoIrUE5jGbaw6TpvYDSrqwqfgBqwRvy2wCjfxBThCmLQRXbCxLHvee9@bScLyScZkXYdqYfTIpDc8hyXtef2iEDMFvrOP1a56qp6dfXH21dk3Z9@d3Tq78wPCj5PDFZOGaQ6cBiTB9zIRkhMYZRpKSsmd12knxzoXanbNFhCx@IpPNQxYoSFB3dkpHn0dqpjfAg/I2KQwpxQf1@jYQU3rEapJzlOuNI8PaR0xJdCXslENMqM0rAPSSMk0ywlEWYnFzgPSPaD8Z@keg7H0x/e9s58/X1ssGSp9IVYi5jAPyJ@RpHuuuMnehw@XhsniuIdImgKQ7jITqoHxqwd/L1kiQhuP32VjsPE2XoQkzap67Q0b13V9spK/) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs prefix notation using Charcoal operators and digits (note that it's not valid Charcoal code due to the omission of `¦` separators between the digits, and it still wouldn't be useful without the `Ｉ` cast operator). Explantion:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔”y⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹”ε
```

Assign the list of Charcoal's digits.

```
≔⁰η
```

Start checking starting at `0000000000` and working up.

```
Ｗ¬ω«
```

Repeat until we have an answer.

```
≔⭆◧Ｉηχ§εΣκζ
```

Convert the current trial index to a 10-digit number in Charcoal digits.

```
≦⊕η
```

Increment the trial index.

```
¿⬤ε№ζκ
```

If this is a permutation of the 10 digits, then...

```
ＦＸ⁴¦⁹«
```

Loop over all operator combinations,

```
≔⭆⁹§”y⁺×⁻Ｘ”÷κＸ⁴λδ
```

convert each into a string of operators,

```
¿⁼Ｖ⁺δ⪫ζ´¦θ
```

compare the value with `n`,

```
≔δω
```

and set the result if it matches.

```
»»ωζ
```

Output the resulting operator string and digits.

96-byte version that can actually finish in under a minute on very simple examples:

```
Ｎθ≔”y⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹”ε≔ＶεηＷ¬ω«≔⭆◧Ｉηχ§εΣκζ≦⊖ι≦⊕η¿⬤ε№ζκＷ∧¬ω‹ιＸ⁴¦⁹«≔⭆⁹§”y⁺×⁻Ｘ”÷ιＸ⁴λδ¿⁼Ｖ⁺δ⪫ζ´¦θ≔δω≦⊕ι»»ωζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNbsIwEIXX5BRWVrbkSiB1g1ihwiIVRZE4gUsGYtU4EDukomLhU/QGXVf9hbar9Ca@QI@QOmkkiqpuLGvezJtv3jRm6TRhoiwDucz0OFtcQopXpOf1leJziX1r7ot98VA8WvNkzbM1L9a8WrOzZu9TBIfO4ZqJjGnAQCiKXT2PuQCEx4nGOSHoxms1nROdcjm/YEscsmgEM43PmNI4dnOdtnv6OpARXGOgaJIt8BUhrrhxji0303gMYJrCAqSGiCJ@rAXyl1aRtPgM4b4QleNZkkmNNxRVtqhh7Muo4aRoBEphTlGY5C6KU4q6hPzg/@XvHmBdUG@ft9a8f33sXDCB1AO@5hEcWQlS3xJVTDXUcJUxoQ7ZhSJT2FGfJ1xWkH5x59cjK4fQrHdyXhuAUID@ObuOZOttvdCxVof1mp/LsSw77XZ5shbf) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>200</s> <s>194</s> <s>186</s> 178 bytes

*-6, -2, -6, -8 bytes, and a test runner thanks to @Mukundan314.*

```python
lambda n:next(s for o in product(*[[*"+-*","**"]]*9)for l in permutations("0123456789")if eval(s:="("*8+l[9]+')'.join(o[i]+str(l[i])for i in range(9)))==n)
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online! (5 digits case)](https://tio.run/##JY5BTsQwDEX3OUWUzSQpjBiaSqhST1K6CDQtRqkdJR7EnL40xQv7y3p@cnrwF2H7lvK@Du979NvH7CX2GH5ZF7lQliQBZco03z9Z23G0qnm26klZq6bJOlOZeDIhb3f2DIRFq5fba@uUgUWGHx916QellW2bOLqpuZjL9ZsANY0wNYWzjkc4VVBV2eMatDPGDAMasWTaJHDITBSLhC1RZrv/T1keRYjzC8BQr4/FtfAM2At5VMqArFdde0UO694J14nu9gc)

Outputs in infix notation with parentheses, using `+-*` respectively for addition, subtraction, and multiplication; uses `**` and exponentiation. The program generates Python code that gets eval'd to check for equivalence to `n`.

Slightly more-readable version with a variable for the number of digits:

```python
L=9
import itertools as i
def g(n):
    for l in i.permutations(map(str,range(1,L+1))):
        for o in i.product("+-*m",repeat=L-1):
            s=l[L-1]
            for j in range(L-1):
                s='('+s+o[j]+l[j]+')'
            s=s.replace("m","**")
            if eval(s)==n:
                return s
```

Comment: @Mukundan314 incorporated those last two edits and saved an extra 2 bytes by rewriting into a one-liner

Comment: In your current code `0**<negative number>` is possible this throws an error halting the program

Comment: My code only proves that all number till be 100k can be formed with expression of the form `<9 operators><a permutation of 0123456789>` in polish notation . it does **not** prove that all number till 100k can be formed with expression of the form alternating digit and operator in polish notation

Comment: @Mukundan314 Oh, I see. I happened to change it from left-associative infix to right-associative infix, which switched polish and reverse polish notation. I switched association order now, so it is now fixed and raises StopIteration for unobtainable `n` (the 0**<negative number> only happened in rare cases because it only reached that state after 0+(...), which could normally yield a solution).

Comment: Wow, the 3.8 assignment expr is going to be very useful; it seems like it was made for golfing

Comment: [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##JU7LboQwDLzzFVEumwS6avfREiS@hHJIS2BdBTtKvFX36ylpffCMrHk4PvhGeG5j2pb@fQtu/ZicwA79D6ssZkoiNIYEoIiJpvsnq@jTemfHQJiVfH45nS/X17fWSt2YYTCyfjKykcbIcTRWwyz8twsqd71U0rR1GOxYH/Th@EWAigYY68xJhZ3oUgelKzlcvLJa675HXc2JVgHsExOFLGCNlNhs/yjyI1fV36eAvrj3wzHzBNhVYp@YAFktquwi2VO3y7U62V8 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") by merging the for loops

Comment: [160 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dc3dDoIgGADQ@56CcSN8krPsR918EmKOUosGfAywrae3zguc8M0v9E0b4vYcbpvV7j5p4nuZyIIRUFhiPAkRp/WRGUgJtNwDFRSAKgWdCHN0a9bZoE@M1odjczpfrm1HOTcLmT/astQPlFFoSys7VRa8qN5oPHM6sJRjNY56msZR/C/O@TB4JWu1WyI6YvIcM6JNxLiAMcO2/QA "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 26 bytes

*+5 bytes for a fix based on Kevin Cruijssen*

```
“+×*_”ṗ9
⁵ḶŒ!p¢ż/€Ẏ€V=¥ƇḢḢ
```

Brute force, like the 05AB1E answer, so it is also extremely slow.

Outputs in infix notation with `+×*_` to represent addition, multiplication, exponentiation, and subtraction respectively. All operators have equal precedence. Similarly to my Python answer, this generates an expression and evals it to find what it evaluates to.

[Try it online (in a version that allows you to enter the number of digits)](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rwxztw9O14h81zH24c/qxyVzHJj/cse3oJMWCQ4uO7tF/1LTm4a4@IBlme2jpsfaHOxYB0f//plwm/40MAA) The value for `n` should be provided as the first argument, while the input should consist of two lines: the first equal to the number of digits; the second less by one.

#### Explanation (going to update soon, I should be able to golf a bit off):

```
“+×*_”ṗ9           # literal string "+×*_" (Jelly arithmetic symbols) Cartesian power 9

⁵ḶŒ!p¢ż/€Ẏ€V=¥ƇḢḢ
⁵Ḷ                 # lowered_range(10): [0,1,2,3,...,9]
  Œ!               # all permutations of these digits
    p              # Cartesian product with
     ¢             # the list of all permutations of 9 arithmetic symbols
      ż/€Ẏ€        # zip and tighten each to squeeze together (golfportunity?)
           V=¥Ƈ    # Filter for those that evaluate to
               Ḣ   # n (surely there is a way around this)
                Ḣ  # get the first one
```

If no string works (which could occur if `n` is too large or the number of digits is decreased), then it outputs `0`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen working on fixing the duplicate number, but 80 was the first test case I tried that worked well with 4 digits

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fixed the issue (80 is slightly-humorously unobtainable with 4 digits). The 26-byte version involved almost completely rewriting from scratch, but I have a 28-byte version that is less-modified from the previous attempt: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Y5Ic7thU8apijfXi6VvyjhrnFJkcnFRydpPioaY1bMVB25zQgK8z20NJj7Q93LAKi//9NuCz@GxoAAA

Comment: Looks good. +1 from me, and I've deleted my comments. :) Looking forward seeing that updated explanation. PS: Jelly doesn't have a `find_first` builtin, instead of the filter + head? I indeed couldn't find one on the Wiki page, but maybe I looked past it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good idea. There is `#` for `find_first_n`, which should save me 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
hfqQ.vjdsT*^"+-*^"9.pUT
```

[Try it online! (5 digit case)](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyOtMFCvLCulOEQrTklbF0iY6BWEmv7/b2QMAA)

#### Explanation

```
hfqQ.vjdsT*^"+-*^"9.pUT
h                        : first element of
 f                       : filter on
          *              : cartesian product of
           ^"+-*^"9      : all 9 length string that can be formed with the chars +, -, * and ^
                   .pUT  : and all permutations of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  qQ                     : for equality of input and
    .vjdsT               : evaluated result of operators and permutation joined with spaces
```